# When digest loop is called, how to $watch know value change at back - end?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to know about how the digest cycle works at **back end** of **angularjs** with respect to `$watch`

How does `$watch` handle a new value in comparison with the old value?

When the digest loop is called, how does `$watch` know the value change in angular's back-end?

Thank you!

Comment: Can you define what you mean by "back - end"?

Comment: thanks @DavinTryon, i think "back-end" is method to check value change from angularjs..

Comment: How Angular works underneath the hood? How do we get this magical data binding to work in only a few lines of code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what you mean by back-end. I am assuming that you are asking how do you know if some other action has changes your model object, value etc.
Here is some pseudo example..

```
scope.$watch('lastLatency', function (val) {... you got your new value here ....}
```

In this example "lastLatency" value is being watched to take action.

Comment: thank for your answer! 

My question is how to angularjs know lastLatency change? and how to angularjs check value it?

Comment: How Angular works underneath the hood? How do we get this magical data binding to work in only a few lines of code?

Answer (score 1):

$watch registers a listener function that is called whenever the given expression changes by comparing the old and new expressions with === in the digest loop.

This is pretty well explained in the docs

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$watch

Comment: How Angular works underneath the hood? How do we get this magical data binding to work in only a few lines of code?

Comment: I haven't looked too much at this myself, but I think your best bet here is to go straight to the source. https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/rootScope.js#L213